# How do I connect to an AWS MySQL database in node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js, amazon-web-services

I have node.js Lambda function on AWS and a MySQL database. I have been using the following code to connect:

```
const mysql = require('mysql');

const con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "<endpoint>",
    user: "<user>",
    password: "<password>"
});


con.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("Connected!");
    con.end();
});
```

When I try to connect to the endpoint I get the message:

```
{"message": "Internal server error"}
```

Any help would be much appreciated! Hope everyone is healthy.

Answer (score 1):

It is most likely an RDS set-up.
Check the security settings on your security group.

Does it have a rule that only allows a connection from a certain security group?

Also, does your RDS have Public Accessibility? you would want to set it to 'Yes'

The port seems to be missing in your ***createConnection*** function, I've seen people skip this while others needed to have it.

Another thing for debugging purpose get the stack as well, it will take you there :)

```
conn.connect(function(err){
  if (err){
   console.error('db connection failed: ' + err.stack);
   return;
  }
 console.log('connected to db');
});
connection.end();
```

Check this [link to AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-nodejs.rds.html), it is for elastic beanstalk, but it's the same :)

Here is another link/blog post to get you there: [using was rds with nodejs](https://stackabuse.com/using-aws-rds-with-node-js-and-express-js/)